# problem sending zip archive compressed in Python but trying to decompress in Rust

Tags: python, rust, gzip

I have this code that compresses data with `zlib` (`gzip`) in Python

```
dta = bytes(str("..."))
res = zlib.compress(dta)
with open('packed.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(t)
```

and I would like to open it in Rust

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder; // flate2 = "1.0"
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("packed.gz").unwrap();
    let mut d = GzDecoder::new(f);
    let mut s = String::new();
    d.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

and I get

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "invalid gzip header" }', src/main.rs:11:30
```

is there a problem with differences in file format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that there is `ZlibDecoder` in `flate2`... and it works

Answer (score 2):

The data stream generated by your python program is not actually a `.gz`-file, it's a raw DEFLATE-stream. If you want a `.gz`-file (including a gz-header, which `flate2::read::GzDecoder` expects), use the `gzip` module in Python. If you do want a raw DEFLATE-stream (as produced by `zlib.compress`), use `flate2::read::DeflateDecoder` to decompress the data.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that `zlib` compression is gzip compatible as mentioned by the python [stdlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html). That is because zlib and gzip both use the `deflate` compression standard.

`zlib` produces a raw deflate compressed byte stream. On the other hand `gzip` is a standard for single compression which wraps the compressed stream over deflate. So If you strip out the file headers from the gzip file, you can decompress using the raw deflate library.

The `zlib` compressed stream for the string `This is the raw string` looks like

```
>>> import zlib
>>> data = bytes(str("This is the raw string"), encoding="utf-8")
>>> res = zlib.compress(data)
>>> print(res)
b'x\x9c\x0b\xc9\xc8,V\x00\xa2\x92\x8cT\x85\xa2\xc4r\x85\xe2\x92\xa2\xcc\xbct\x00ZI\x08\x17'
```

Which is (when you send it to `xxd`.

```
00000000: 789c 0bc9 c82c 5600 a292 8c54 85a2 c472  x....,V....T...r
00000010: 85e2 92a2 ccbc 7400 5a49 0817            ......t.ZI..
```

The first 2 bytes declare the type of the file.

```
78 01 - No Compression/low
78 9C - Default Compression
78 DA - Best Compression
```

In our case, it's `78 9C` which is zlib with default compression which is what python says in its docs. You can verify this by running

```
file package.gz
```

It should say `zlib compressed data` as that's what the file's header look like.

If we try to compress using gzip, let's see what comes up.

```
>>> import gzip
>>> data = bytes(str("This is the raw string"), encoding="utf-8")
>>> gzip.compress(data)
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xd6\x1bw_\x02\xff\x0b\xc9\xc8,V\x00\xa2\x92\x8cT\x85\xa2\xc4r\x85\xe2\x92\xa2\xcc\xbct\x00&\x91\x1a\x82\x16\x00\x00\x00'
```

If you notice the hex dump

```
00000000: 1f8b 0800 d61b 775f 02ff 0bc9 c82c 5600  ......w_.....,V.
00000010: a292 8c54 85a2 c472 85e2 92a2 ccbc 7400  ...T...r......t.
00000020: 2691 1a82 1600 0000                      &.......
```

The magic number shows, `1f 8b` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)). If you look past the headers, you will see that both the hex dumps contain the same compressed data, which is
For zlib

```
00000000: .... 0bc9 c82c 5600 a292 8c54 85a2 c472  x....,V....T...r
00000010: 85e2 92a2 ccbc 7400 .... ....            ......t.ZI..
```

and, for gzip

```
00000000: .... .... .... .... .... 0bc9 c82c 5600  ......w_.....,V.
00000010: a292 8c54 85a2 c472 85e2 92a2 ccbc 7400  ...T...r......t.
00000020: .... .... .... ....                      &.......
```

So If you [ask rust to use the correct decoder](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19ba2478bd248f825f755eeecdf25c07), it will surely work. That's the benefit of standards.

So, gzip is just a container over the zlib container. I have not explained what the other bytes in the hexdump mean (because I haven't looked it up yet).